# map datatable to class And Change Type Int To Enum

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i have one Stored Procedure that return one select 
like this :

```
select name , family , sex from person
```

i have one class that named person like this :

```
 public class person {
         string name {get;set;}
         string family {get;set;}
         GenderEnum sex {get;set;}
       }
```

and i have one Enum that named GenderEnum Like This :

```
Enum GenderEnum
{
Man = 1 ,
Woman = 2 ,
}
```

i want convert my datatable to IList of Person .

My problem is : when i want convert sex column to sex field i most cast or convert type int in to GenderEnum.

do not forget that i most have one generic method for convert all DataTable to All Class
and this Method most recognize each properties have enum type .

this method map all column to all properties According to Name

i write this method but this do not work with all type.

for exapmle : if my column be int and my Properties be strinbe and have same name , map not work.

```
public List<T> ConvertTo<T>(DataTable datatable) where T : new()
    {
        var temp = new List<T>();
        try
        {
            var columnsNames = (from DataColumn dataColumn in datatable.Columns select dataColumn.ColumnName).ToList();
            temp = datatable.AsEnumerable().ToList().ConvertAll<T>(row => GetObject<T>(row, columnsNames));
            return temp;
        }
        catch
        {
            return temp;
        }

    }
private T GetObject<T>(DataRow row, List<string> columnsName) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        try
        {
            string columnname = "";

            PropertyInfo[] Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo objProperty in Properties)
            {
                columnname = columnsName.Find(name => name.ToLower() == objProperty.Name.ToLower());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnname))
                {
                    var value = row[columnname];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    {

                        Type type;

                        type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) ?? objProperty.PropertyType;

                        objProperty.SetValue(obj,
                                             type == value.GetType()
                                                 ? Convert.ChangeType(value, type)
                                                 : System.Enum.ToObject(type, value), null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking for trouble with this **GetObject** method and you'd be better off to switch to EF or (virtually) any other ORM since what you're doing is extremely risky. Consider the maintainability and readability of this code. However, I understand that you probably are under pressure of a deadline and can't do much about it at this stage.

To provide a quick fix for your problem, please consider modifying your **Person** class as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Family { get; set; }

    public Int32 Sex  { get; set; }

    public GenderEnum EnumeratedSex
    {
        get
        {
            return Sex == 1 ? GenderEnum.Man : GenderEnum.Woman;
        }
    }
}

public enum GenderEnum
{
    Man = 1,
    Woman = 2
}
```

I believe that your Sex field is simply an int in the database, but if not, please change it accordingly.

Please let me know if this is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this, why don't try to use Entity framework for this?? see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for your reference

Comment: i use EF for smal query. this query have very join and sub query and etc. i most use SP for retern dataset. and then i most convert dataset to class.

Comment: I guess EF will be a better way to this than thinking of doing those things. and it's more precise though